# How to get a set of unique values from many lists efficiently (Python)

Tags: python, performance, set, unique

I have many (about 6000) text files with a list of IDs in each (each ID in file on a new row). There could be from 10000 to 10 million IDs in each file.

How to get a set of unique IDs from all these files?

My current code looks like this:

```html
import glob
kk=glob.glob('C://Folder_with_all_txt_files/*')
ID_set=set()
for source in kk:
    a=[]
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(source, 'rt'))
    for row in csvReader:
        a.append(row)
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        a[i]=a[i][0]
    s=set(a)
    ID_set=ID_set.union(s)
    del a,s
```

Problems with the current code:

- 1) Consumes too much RAM
- 2) Too slow

Is there a more efficient way to do this task?

Also, is it possible to use all CPU cores in this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Skip the creation of set *s*.  Just *update* the *ID_set* directly.
- Depending on what the files look like, you can just use *read()* and *str.split()* rather than the CSV reader.

Perhaps something like this will work for your dataset:

```
import glob

id_set = set()
for filename in glob.glob('C://Folder_with_all_txt_files/*'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        ids = f.read().split()
        id_set.update(ids)
```

Comment: Thanks! works way faster now.. But still consumes lots of RAM(

Answer (score 0):

This approach may be a little slower than Raymond's, but it avoids loading each file into memory at once:

```
import glob

ids = set()
for filename in glob.glob('C://Folder_with_all_txt_files/*'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for id_ in f:
            ids.add(id_.strip())
```